# Google Transit API bus stops in route invisible and on the map disabled

Tags: jquery-mobile, google-maps-api-3, google-api

I can't get information from clicking the bus stops although the city has them when I enter in Google Maps, but implementing it myself doesn't work. They are disabled. 
I'm having a similar problem to another post:
[Enable bus stop icons clickable in Google Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11920059/enable-bus-stop-icons-clickable-in-google-maps)

Also when I create a route my stops between the origin and destination don't appear, these white dots are invisible, but if I click in the instructions in the panel this window opens with the information needed.

I've tried out putting transit layer and nothing appears in my jQuery Mobile app.

[image]

Any ideas to get this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found part of the solution. I couldn't see the white dots in the route because when I was creating the direction display I was suppressing markers to get my custom markers instead of the usual Google Map ones. But also I was suppressing the middle points that I needed!

Instead of this:

```
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({suppressMarkers: true});
```

I've changed it for this:

```
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
```

So now I can see the dots:
[image]

I still can't get the bus stops information when clicking an icon

Answer (score 3):

You can't get the interactive functionality out of the API that the normal map.google.com has. Using the transit layer gives you a visual display of the transit system, but there's an open bug ticket on this issue: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=145.

Even in the official Maps api code demo of a transit layer for London, the transit icons are non-interactive, while on map.google.com they are clickable: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-transit.